# Numpy operation result is printed like a list rather than numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to concatenate two arrays vertically in Python using the NumPy package but i need a different output.

i have two lists

```py
a=[1,2,3]
b=[7,8,9]
```

I wrote this to solve the problem

```py
a1 = np.array(a)
a2 = np.array(b)
np.vstack((a1,a2))
```

My output is

```py
[[1 2 3]
 [7 8 9]]
```

but i need an output like this

```py
array([[1, 2, 3],
[7, 8, 9]])
```

What am i missing? Thank you

Comment: Those are the same thing...you're probably just wrapping it in a `print()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result is correctly an `np.ndarray`. To see this, you need its [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) rather than printout:

```
In [4]: np.vstack((a1,a2))

Out[4]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [5]: print _4
[[1 2 3]
 [7 8 9]]

In [6]: _4
Out[6]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [8]: print repr(_4)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```